# Stop optimistic lock exception

Tags: java, jpa, version

I have an application at which data will be exported to XML file. Then this XML file must be imported from another application that has the same entities. This entities contain the @version annotation. My problem is that when I try to import the data in the second application an optimistic lock exception is thrown since the version field is higher than what it should be.

So is there a way to stop the @version annotation when importing these files, or is there another solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which tool you have used to export your db/entity into xml. You can remove your version from the xml during export. For example JAXB does it using annotation `@XmlTransient`

Similarly, when doing update during your import. You can also set the version field as `null` before doing the operation.

Comment: used jaxb, making it transient is not efficient since data might be resent to the first application so transient mean version = 0 while in the first application it will be different than that.